# A weird org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException which happen only if my web app is deployed to tomcat on CentOS

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I am creating a java web app running on Spring framework, Tomcat, Hibernate(but, only JPA API). I've written some code that connects to database with named queries that are externalized into xml files like:

this web app is working fine on my local tomcat on OS X. but it is not working on CentOS machine. when it is deployed on CentOS, initialization of Spring context fails due to:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate query mapping ProductReview.getProductReviewNamedParameter
```

From my knowledge, DuplicateMappingException should happen when the `ProductReview.getProductReviewNamedParameter` named query is defined two or more times. but I defined exactly once and this app working fine on my local machine. Has anyone experienced a similar problem like me? Any answers, your experiences, or insights would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

```
classpath*:jpql-mapper/**/*.xml
```

classpath* searches the whole classpath for all occurrences of this file pattern. So if you accidentally have your named queries twice in the classpath, this would explain the exception.

So as a first step remove the '*' after classpath, so it looks like :

```
classpath:jpql-mapper/**/*.xml
```

The way the classpath is built and also the jars contained (tomcats own jars, versions), may be different in the two environments. This may lead to  different behaviour, as you experienced.

Comment: you've just told me about the jar file, I looked at both jar files that contains .xml files on OS X and CentOS. the one on CentOS has two .xml files with same name when issuing `jar tf`. Thank you for your insight.